# Cannot deploy React app to Firebase hosting properly from github Action

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github-actions

I can deploy React app to Firebase properly but If I try to deploy from Github Actions, It can't be deployed(404 error).

The directory structure is like this:

```
- github
  - workflow
    - action.yaml
- public
  - sub-dir(React App)
    - build
```

When I deploy a project with this command,
`firebase deploy --only hosting`

It will run correctly.
(The URL is [my-domain]/sub-dir/build)

but when it is deployed from github actions, getting 404 error page even though accessing the same URL.

this is the statement of action.yaml

```
name: Continuous Deployment

on:
  push:
    ### Triggers a push to the main branch and executes the process
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: checkout branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: configure git info
        run: |
          git remote set-url origin https://github-actions:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}
          git config --global user.name "${GITHUB_ACTOR}"
          git config --global user.email "${GITHUB_ACTOR}@users.noreply.github.com"

      - name: check git status and branch
        run: |
          git status
          git branch

      ### sub-dir build
      - name: sub-dir build
        run: |
          cd public/sub-dir
          yarn install
          yarn build

      - name: push the built project
        run: |
          git add .
          git commit -m "Push different part from GitHub Actions"
          git push origin HEAD:${GITHUB_REF}

      ### Firebase deploy
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "14.18.3"
          cache: npm
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Install Functions Dependencies
        run: |
          node -v
          cd functions && npm install
          npm i -g firebase-tools
          firebase --version
          git pull origin HEAD:${GITHUB_REF}
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.11",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25"
  },
  "homepage": "./"
}
```

I have no idea about the reason. I would be happy to get the answer to this.

Thank you in advance.